# buttonset() not working with dynamic inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I'm trying to use jquery buttonset() for dymanic inputs but it's not working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var N = 30;
    for (var i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        $('<label/>', {
            id: "label-" + i,
        }).append($('<input/>', {
            type: "checkbox",
            id: "checkbox-" + i
        })).append(i).prependTo("#showChck");
    }

    $("#showChck").buttonset('refresh');
});
```

Only the label is shown, not the input.

Edit: Add html code:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="channels" style="display:none;">
    <fieldset id="showChck" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">

    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: would it be possible to show the html code, if possible?

Comment: sorry, I thought it was irrelevant

Comment: it helps when you're doing DOM manipulation so the structure can be quickly seen instead of inferred. just in case there's something else that might be messing up the code is all. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label needs `for` attribute for buttonset to work and also labels and checkboxes should not be nested.

In the demo, I changed the way inputs and labels are rendered **[as per the documentation here](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/)**

*Documentation says*

> For the association to work properly, give the input an id attribute, and refer to that in the label's for attribute. Don't nest the input inside the label, as that causes accessibility problems.

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var N = 30;
  for (var i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    var $input = $('<input/>', {
      type: "checkbox",
      id: "checkbox-" + i
    });
    var $label = $('<label/>', {
      id: "label-" + i,
      for: "checkbox-" + i
    }).append(i);
    $("#showChck").append($input).append($label);
  }
  $("#showChck").buttonset();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var N = 30;
  for (var i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    var $input = $('<input/>', {
      type: "checkbox",
      id: "checkbox-" + i
    });
    var $label = $('<label/>', {
      id: "label-" + i,
      for: "checkbox-" + i
    }).append(i);
    $("#showChck").append($input).append($label);
  }
  $("#showChck").buttonset();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="channels" style="display:block;">
  <fieldset id="showChck" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">

  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Would it be a problem if I put the label + input into a div? So I don't have to hide/show() both, that's why I nested.

Comment: Hmm now that I realize the order of the checkboxes... in my page i see from 30 to 1 instead of the code snippet order, you know why???

Comment: because if you use append, it adds to the end, you might want to use $.prepend

Comment: @ChazyChaz: In your code, you are using prepend which is causing the problem. Are you sure you are still using append ?

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla Jquery includes a prepend method that's not the issue, i believe it was the for attributes that was causing the probelm (see http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Comment: @Daemedeor: I thought OP was using this piece of code http://jsbin.com/gawemi/1/edit?js,output instead of something like this 

http://jsbin.com/joluge/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: oh sorry @DhirajBodicherla

Comment: @Daemedeor: no problemo :)

Comment: Sorry if I caused a mess with the code. The code should be intended to create hidden checkboxes and show/hide them using a slider, so they should be hidden until the slider make them apper based on the value (ui.value). The code was using prependTo (as in the question) but i switch it to appendTo and now they are created in order (from 1 to 30) but for some reason the slider is showing the 30 first...

Comment: oh, that sounds a bit more complicated. How about posting a new question ?

Comment: Sure, I'm going to post it now. Thanks.